# Using DSolve to solve the Hypergeometric ODE in terms of Legendre Polynomials

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, special-functions, algebraic-manipulation

I have been curious about if is it possible to "Force" `DSolve` to get solutions of differential equations in terms of another related functions.

Eg. The hypergeometric ODE is naturally solved in terms of the 2F1 functions.

```
fun = 
 y[x] /. DSolve[(x (1 - x) y''[x] + (c - (a + b + 1) x) y'[x] - 
       a b y[x]) == 0, y[x], x][[1]]
(* C[1] Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, x] + (-1)^(1 - c) x^(1 - c) C[
  2] Hypergeometric2F1[1 + a - c, 1 + b - c, 2 - c, x] *)
```

However, there is a close relation in between both the Legendre polynomials and the Hypergeometric polynomials, as shown here:

https://dlmf.nist.gov/14.3.E1

Is there a way to tell `DSolve` to try by using Legendre Polynomials to solve the equation?

Or is there any way of trying to re express the solution as Legendre Polynomials?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use a replacement rule to re-express hypergeometrics as Legendres

Comment: The 2F1 Hypergeometric function is only a Legendre function for certain values of the parameters a,b,c, as you can see from the DLMF reference you provided.

Comment: @TomDickens a better try for this question would be in how to "Force" DSolve to give solutions of Legendre DE as Hypergeometric functions.